# KeyError: 'receiver' in self.scope[]

Tags: django, django-channels, keyerror

I am trying to retrieve data through self.scope[] in Django channels but I keep getting `KeyError`. How can I get the `receiver` part through `self.receiver_username` without the error? See the code details below:

`consumers.py`

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.receiver_username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['receiver']

        self.accept()
```

`routing.py`

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/socket-server/(?P<receiver>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

`chat.html`

```
<div id="chat-messages"></div>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type a message...">
    <input type="text" name="receiver" value="test">
    <button id="send-button">Send</button>
</form>

<div id="messages"></div>

<script>
    var receiver = 'test';

    let url = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket-server/` + receiver + '/'

        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url)

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
            let data = JSON.parse(e.data)

            if(data.type === 'chat'){
                let messages = document.getElementById('messages')

                messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>
                                        <p>${data.message}</p>
                                    </div>`)
            }
    }

    let form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        let message = e.target.message.value
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }))
        form.reset()
    })
</script>
```

When I try to retrieve the `var receiver` through `self.receiver_username`, I got the following error:

```
KeyError: 'receiver'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/socket-server/test/ [127.0.0.1:51206]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.